# Getting Started with hadoop on windows

Tags: hadoop

I am a newbie here. I just love to code and develop own programs...Day before yesterday I got an idea to set Hadoop on windows. I just fetched all the stacks but could not successfully install it. I am attaching screenshots together with my query. My windows version is 8.1 64 bit.

[image: Error which I get while checking Hadoop -version]

Answer (score 0):

The snapshot that you provided says that the `JAVA_HOME` is not set correctly, can you make sure that `JAVA_HOME` is set properly in your system?
Please verify `javac` and `java` commands works from your command prompt.
**OR** can you please provide hadoop-env.cmd content? so that we can find out the root cause?

Comment: my hadoop-env.cmd The java implementation to use.  Required.
set JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\jdk1.8.0_191

Comment: Are you able to run javac and java commands from command prompt?

Comment: yes javac-version command gives me `javac 1.8.0_191` same does the java -version also `echo %JAVA_HOME%` gives the path of java.exe which is `C:\PROGRA~1\java\jdk1.8.0_191`

Comment: I think somewhere it is setting Xmx512m which is not set correctly.

Comment: can you explain please how to set Xmx512m??